kibana in air-gapped/ restrict environment solution
I have successfully deployed an ECE cluster, including APM, Kibana, ML, and Elasticsearch (master and data tiers). I can access Kibana via the endpoint, and it is functioning correctly. However, this deployment is in a restricted environment with no internet access. Kibana is attempting to connect to the Elastic package repository for certain features that require internet access. I need assistance in configuring Kibana to operate fully in this restricted, air-gapped environment. Could you please provide support on how to achieve this?
I researched the official documentation but all in vain.

Does following this doc for xpack-fleet solve your issues? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.15/air-gapped.html

as @IanGabes said, you can host your own registry: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.15/air-gapped.html#air-gapped-diy-epr that should solve this for you.
